# Haskell: How to parse an IO input string into a Float (or Int or whatever)?

Tags: parsing, haskell, input, io, floating-point

I am trying to make a program that takes a Float number inputted by the user via keyboard and does stuff with it.

However every time I try to parse the inputted String into a Float I keep getting errors.  Every single method I've tried has failed to allow me to take user inputted data and turn it into a Float, which is what I need.

My practice program (not the actual problem I'm trying to solve) is:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Please input a number."
    inputjar <- getLine
    read :: read a => String -> a
    putStrLn( read inputjar :: Int)
```

### Edit

A further question.

How do I take the inputted string and turn it into something I can use in a calculation?

For example, how do I take the inputted string so that I can do something like:

```
(var + var) / 2
```

Comment: Could you explain why you have the `read :: read a => String -> a` expression? (This is a serious question: [explaining your own code in detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is a really good way of understanding and debugging.)

Comment: A friend who was helping me told me to put that in or read wouldn't work.  I was pretty much trying anything at that point and thought it was needed.

Comment: I think the friend meant that you might wrap your use of `read` with a specialization of its signature, e.g. `print ((read :: String -> Int) inputjar)` (We use print here because it is the number, not a string that we are working with.) The compiler already knows the most general type of `read` i.e. `Read a => String -> a` and this won't help it figure out what the user's input means.  In this case you can also do `print (read inputjar ::Int)` -- your main error above was using `putStrLn`, which acts only on strings, rather than print.

Comment: @PhilipEloy: Since "Someone answered it on this page" please accept the relevant answer. If someone else asked basically the same question and the answer is in that question please link to it in a comment so we can close this one as a duplicate linking to the other question.

Answer (score 11):

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Please input a number."
   inputjar <- readLn
   print (inputjar :: Int)
```

This is in a way nicer since it immediately fixes what we're reading the string as:

```
main = do
   putStrLn "Please input a number."
   inputjar :: Int  <- readLn
   print inputjar
```

but it requires `{-#LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables#-}`

Comment: `inputjar <- readLN :: IO Int`, no extensions. My preferred method.

Comment: Same here; I was resisting typing with `IO` in this context.

Comment: @applicative Is it bad to typecast IO like this? Seems the easiest solution but sounds like you have your reservations.

Answer (score 5):

You say `(read inputjar :: Int)` in your code, but you're telling us that you want to read a `Float`.  You are not defining `read`, take that line out.  You use `putStrLn` so that you can print out the float, but `putStrLn` takes a `String`, so you need to `show` the value.

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Please input a number."
    inputjar <- getLine
    putStrLn $ show (read inputjar :: Float)
```

Answer (score 5):

`putStrLn` prints out `String`s, not `Int`s, so there are two solutions:

Use `print`, which prints anything that implements `Show`:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Please input a number."
    inputjar <- getLine
    let n = read inputjar :: Int
    print n
```

.. or call `putStrLn` on the original `String` that you read in

```
main = do
    putStrLn "Please input a number."
    inputjar <- getLine
    let n = read inputjar :: Int
    putStrLn inputjar
```

In the latter example n is never used, but presumably you would write some code after that which would actually use it.

Answer (score 3):

Well I guess the

```
read :: read a => String -> a
```

is there just by mistake?

Anyway, under ghci, `:t putStrLn` shows:

```
putStrLn :: String -> IO ()
```

So `putStrLn` only accepts String as its first parameter, so if you really want to:

```
putStrLn( show (read inputjar :: Int))
```

BTW, `read inputjar :: int` is correct, only your ouput is wrong.

Comment: ok, that worked.  That's fantastic.  Thank you.

If I want to use the contents of inputjar for something else (say an actual calculation) what else would I need to do?

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me

```
import System.IO

getNum :: IO Integer 
getNum = readLn 

--call function like this
something <- getNum
--something is type Integer
```