# How to read in an Int and use it in another function

Tags: parsing, haskell, io

I am trying to read in an Int and then use the read value in a pure function, but it does not seem to work properly. After searching through a lot of resources I use the from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11481306/haskell-how-to-parse-an-io-input-string-into-a-float-or-int-or-whatever).

So my code goes as the following:

```
main = do
putStrLn "Please input a number."
inputjar <- getLine
return (read inputjar :: Int)
```

Which works fine, but when I want to use it in my pure function:

```
usrSetBrick :: [[Int]] -> [[Int]]
usrSetBrick xs = setBrick (main) (main) (main) xs
```

I get a compile error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Int' with actual type `IO Int'
In the first argument of `setBrick', namely `(main)'
In the expression: setBrick (main) (main) (main) xs
In an equation for `usrSetBrick':
usrSetBrick xs = setBrick (tull) (tull) (tull) xs
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

So from what I understand does main return an int. Even it should, as I can understand from
    return (read inputjar :: Int) 
How can I make the read input usable in my function?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably don't want to be using `main` to return things since it's the entry point to your program.  Instead, you can write a function

```
getInt :: IO Int
getInt = do
    input <- getLine
    return (read input)  -- Don't have to specify Int here, GHC can figure it out from the type signature
```

However, your function `setBrick`, which presumably has the type `Int -> Int -> Int -> [[Int]] -> [[Int]]`, can't use `getInt` directly.  This is by design, Haskell's type system forces you to treat `IO` actions separately from pure functions (once you get used to it, it's a wonderful tool for reasoning about your code).  Instead, you can do something like

```
promptInt :: IO Int
promptInt = do
    putStrLn "Please input a number."
    getInt

usrSetBrick :: [[Int]] -> IO [[Int]]
usrSetBrick xs = do
    a <- promptInt
    b <- promptInt
    c <- promptInt
    return $ setBrick a b c xs
```

The types `Int` and `IO Int` are not the same in Haskell, you can not use the interchangeably.  This holds true for types like `[Int]`, `Maybe Int`, and `Either String Int` as well, none of these the same as `Int`.  Since `main` is an `IO` function, it doesn't return `Int`, it returns `IO Int`.  In fact, `return` is not a special construct in Haskell at all, it's just a normal function that happens to wrap a value in a `Monad`.  In this case, the `Monad` being used is `IO`, so `return (read inputjar :: Int)` has the type `IO Int`.

---

To expand on @Zeta's comment below, Haskell's `return` is not special and more importantly *does not exit functions early*.  The following code will demonstrate this:

```
doSomething :: IO Int
doSomething = do
    return "Test"  -- Wouldn't type-check if this exited early
    return 123     -- Would type check, but is ignored
    putStrLn "You'll see this line printed"
    return ()      -- Doesn't affect anything
    x <- getLine   -- Still happens
    return 5678
    putStrLn "Your input is meaningless!  Here's a 0"
    return ([1, 2], "hello", "world")
    return 0       -- This is the actual return value
```

All those extra returns do nothing in Haskell (at least in the `IO` monad).  All that happens is a value is wrapped in a constructor and chained together with the rest of the statements in that function.  There are even some people in the Haskell community that view `return` as both unnecessary and confusing.  Technically, `return` is equivalent to `pure` for `Applicative`s, and all `Monad`s are also `Applicative`s, so it's not really providing us anything.  At some point in the distant future, it's possible that the `return` function might disappear entirely, being completely superseded by `pure`.  Again, neither of these functions are part of Haskell syntax, they're defined in the core libraries as plain, normal functions.

Comment: I guess you should emphasize a little bit more on the `return` (Haskell) vs `return` (C) issue, that seems to be the thing the user currently gets confused by. (Yes, it's in your last paragraph, but it is currently a little bit hidden. Just saying ^^)